# Running emacs intero-mode with stack docker integration

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-stack, intero

I'm trying to use intero-mode in a stack project that has the docker integration enabled. Therefore its stack.yml contains:

```
docker:
  enable: true
  image: my-project/build:lts-11.9
```

Even though, when I open any .hs file in the project, intero-mode tries to install the intero executable and fails. In the *Messages* buffer it reports:

```
Installed successfully! Starting Intero in a moment ...
Booting up intero ...
Problem with Intero!
Reading Haskell configuration failed with exit code 1 and output:
get-cabal-configuration.hs: /home/jesuspc/.nix-profile/bin/hpack: createProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

And I get the error screen for intero-mode:

```
...
The process ended. Here is the reason that Emacs gives us:

exited abnormally with code 1

For troubleshooting purposes, here are the arguments used to launch intero:

stack ghci --with-ghc /home/jesuspc/.stack/compiler-tools/x86_64-linux-dke094d5208e8a802cb369cecdad3049ae/ghc-8.2.2/bin/intero "--docker-run-args=--interactive=true --tty=false" --no-build --no-load --ghci-options -ignore-dot-ghci my-project
...
```

When I run that line I get:

```
Did not find executable at specified path: /home/jesuspc/.stack/compiler-tools/x86_64-linux-dke094d5208e8a802cb369cecdad3049ae/ghc-8.2.2/bin/intero
```

Which may be something related to nix, because I found that by running instead:

```
stack ghci --with-ghc /home/jesuspc/.stack/compiler-tools/x86_64-linux-nix/ghc-8.2.2/bin/intero "--docker-run-args=--interactive=true --tty=false" --no-build --no-load --ghci-options -ignore-dot-ghci my-project
```

I get a different error:

```
/home/jesuspc/.stack/compiler-tools/x86_64-linux-nix/ghc-8.2.2/bin/intero: createProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

I believe that this error may be thrown because my project uses external libraries and it can not find them, but that's just a guess.

Is intero-mode even aware of the stack-docker integration? It seems to be trying to use the intero executable in my local machine instead of using the docker context, where all the required libraries are present. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this issue yesterday as well.  It looks like the issue is in the function [intero-copy-compiler-tool-auto-install](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/intero/blob/0eec1536a0b051d1628895205c273d498385c7a7/elisp/intero.el#L2214)
which does not take into account your `stack.yaml` file and so does not build `intero` into the docker container.  A super hacky work around I found is to run

```
stack --docker build --copy-compiler-tool intero
```

from within your project.